# Tracking changes to fields using mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out the best way to track changes to fields when using mongoose.js.  For example, every time the `name` field on an object is set, I want to add a new entry to that object's history (as an embedded document) that looks something like `{ field: 'name', previous: 'foo', current: 'bar', date: '3/06/2012 9:06 am' }`.

I started by trying to use a plug-in that hooks `.pre('save')` but I can't figure out which fields have been modified without grabbing the old value from the database and comparing them myself.  Then I thought I could use custom setters, but I ran into the same problem - I don't know which field was modified.  Currently I'm left with doing something like this which hard codes the field name into to the setter:

```
var comment = new Schema({
  name : { type: String, set: trackName },
  history : [Change]
});

var trackName = function(val) {
  var change = new Change;
  change.field = 'name';
  change.previous = this.name;
  change.current = val;
  change.date = Date.now();
  this.history.push(change);
  return val;
}
```

But this means I need a custom setter for each field name that I want to track.  I'm guessing there must be a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like i missed 'Document.modifiedPaths'.  This does exactly what I need to determine which fields have been modified.

Comment: how did you get the old values just using modifiedPaths?

Comment: @Totty.js For anyone who stumbles across this question, mongoose currently doesn't track old values automatically, but here's one solution: https://pste.me/#/FU1Kg

Comment: @helion3 looks like that link is out of date

Comment: This question has solutions to the problem of tracking old values https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195850