# mongoose get db value in pre-save hook

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to know what the 'clean' value of a dirty prop is in a pre-save mongoose hook like this:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    if (user.isModified('password')){
       //i want to know what the value of user.password was before it was changed
    }
    next()
}
```

Is it possible to look up the old value without looking it up in the db?

Answer (score 24):

By default, the old values are not stored. You would have to do is track the old data with a post init hook (a mongoose feature).

What we do is attach copy of the original document to all items pulled from MongoDB. We have this code for each schema we need to get pre-dirty data for comparison:

```
schema.post( 'init', function() {
    this._original = this.toObject();
} );
```

NodeJS is pretty efficient, and does copy on write when possible, so you don't see double the memory consumption unless you modify the entire document. Only then does _original actually consume double the memory.

Answer (score 5):

So in a pre-save hook, from what I can tell by reading [this section of the source code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/25cc8deae1398ade49c67a750b525160aafd3fa0/lib/document.js#L392), I don't think the previous value is stored anywhere. So you'll have to load the document from mongodb to get it.

However, you might want to use the `virtuals` mechanism instead of a pre-save hook to store the old value before changing it to the new value.

```
var virtual = schema.virtual('password');
virtual.set(function (v) {
  var this._oldPassword = this.password;
  return v;
});
```

Experiment with something along those lines and see if you can make something work suitably.

Comment: why do you suggest i use a `virtual` vs `path` ?

Comment: Because `path` just defines the name and type of a data property whereas `virtual` allows you to define a property accessed via get/set methods where you can put code.

Comment: @PeterLyons Sorry for resurrecting old thread, But I think this approach will not work if there are multiple node servers deployed behind load balancer, right?

Comment: @saurabh I think it should work just fine because a single request is always executed on a single node instance. Thus, `this._oldPassword` won't change between definition and usage. It just fails if you need to have a up-to-date value and values might be changed by other requests. But that situation is more complex anyways.

Comment: @Saurabh: why apologize for asking a relevant question? What does the time passed have to do with it?