# How do I use a pre save hook database value in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get the value of an object before the pre-save hook and compare that to the new value. As suggested in [mongoose get db value in pre-save hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192804/mongoose-get-db-value-in-pre-save-hook) and https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2952, I did a post-init hook that copied it to a doc._original. The issue is that I'm not sure how to access this ._original in a different hook.

```
FieldSchema
  .post('save', function (doc) {
    console.log(doc._original);
  });

FieldSchema
  .post('init', function (doc) {
    doc._original = doc.toObject();
  });
```

I know that the doc in the post save hook is different from the doc in the post init hook, but how would I access the original?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only access properties on a database which you have defined in its schema. So since you probably haven't defined `_original` as a property in your schema, you can't access, or even set it.

One way would be to obviously define `_original` in your schema.

But to get and set properties *not* defined in your schema: use `.get`, and `.set` with `{strict:false}`

```
FieldSchema
  .post('save', function (doc) {
    console.log(doc.get('_original'));
  });

FieldSchema
  .post('init', function (doc) {
    doc.set('_original', doc.toObject(), {strict: false});
  });
```

Note the option `{strict: false}` passed to `.set` which is required because you're setting a property not defined in the schema.

---

update:

First thing I didn't notice before is that in your question title you want **pre**-save hook but in your code you actually have a post-save hook (which is what I based my answer on). I hope you know what you're doing, in that post save hook is invoked *after* saving the document.

But in my opinion, and from what I can understand what your original intent was from the question, I think you should actually use a pre-save hook and an async version of it (by passing `next` callback), so that you can **`.find`** (retrieve) the document from the database, which would be the original version since the new version hasn't yet been saved (pre-save) thus enabling you to compare without actually saving any new fields, which seems an anti-pattern to begin with.

So something like:

```
FieldSchema
  .pre('save', function (next) {
    var new_doc = this;
    this.constructor   // ≈ mongoose.model('…', FieldSchema).findById
      .findById(this.id, function(err, original){
        console.log(original);
        console.log(new_doc);
        next();
      });
  });
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: Is one way preferable to another?

Is this also the best way to get the pre-save value, or is there another better way?

Comment: @StanleyYuan sorry I didn't notice this question before. Please checkout the update in my answer. Hope that helps.