# What is the best way to keep track of changes of a document's property in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, backend

I would like to know how to keep track of the values of a document in MongoDB.

It's a MongoDB Database with a Node and Express backend.

Say I have a document, which is part of the Patients collection.

```
{
    "_id": "4k2lK49938d82kL",
    "firstName": "John",
    "objective": "Burn fat"
}
```

Then I edit the "objective" property, so the document results like this:

```
{
    "_id": "4k2lK49938d82kL",
    "firstName": "John",
    "objective": "Gain muscle"
}
```

What's the best/most efficient way to keep track of that change? In other words, I would like to know that the "objective" property had the value "Burn fat" in the past, and access it in the future.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the "Express backend" relevant to the question? Anyway, there are Mongoose plugins that track document changes ([mongoose-track](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-track), [mongoose-history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-history)), so you don't have to reinvent the wheel, which is [non-trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659979/tracking-changes-to-fields-using-mongoose-js).

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining/tracking history in the same document is not all recommended. As the document size will keep on increasing leading to

- probably if there are too many updates, 16mb document size limit
- Performance degrades

Instead, you should maintain a separate collection for history. You might have use hibernates' Javers or envers for auditing for your relational databases. if not you can check how they work. A separate table (xyz_AUD) is maintained for each table (xyz). For each row (with primary key abc) in xyz table, there exist multiple rows in xyz_AUD table, where each row is version of that row.

Moreover, Javers also support MongoDB auditing. If you are using java you can directly use it. No need to write your own logic.

Refer - https://nullbeans.com/auditing-using-spring-boot-mongodb-and-javers/

One more thing, Javers Envers Hibernate are java libraries. But I'm sure for other programming languages also, similar libraries will be present.

There is a mongoose plugin as well -

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-audit (quite oudated 4 years)
- https://github.com/nassor/mongoose-history#readme (better)

Comment: I'm not so worried about document size, as the properties I would like to keep track of would not be edited that often. I would say that mantaining a different collection for history would require a lot more storage (correct me if I'm wrong, it's my assumption), since every edit would be a new object. Thanks for your help Rajat

Answer (score 0):

Maintain it as a sub-document like below

```
{
    "_id": "4k2lK49938d82kL",
    "firstName": "John",
    "objective": {
        obj1: "Gain muscle",
        obj2: "Burn fat"
    }

}
```

You can also maintain it as an array field but remember, mongodb doesn't allow you to maintain uniqueness in an array field and if you plan to index the "objective" field, you'll have to create a multi key index

Comment: Good option, could you please explain more about uniqueness in arrays? I'm not familiar with the concept. Thanks a lot Anban

Comment: In array field, you can maintain duplicate values so you cannot build unique index on it. In mongo, the unique constraint applies to separate documents, for a unique multikey index, a document may have array elements that result in repeating index key values as long as the index key values for that document do not duplicate those of another document

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the type of "objective" to array and track the changes in it. the last one of the array is the latest value.

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first. Do you find any cons about this? Those properties would not be edited so often, so I don't worry about document size. Any further comment is highly appreciated. Thanks Liu!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to use and update an array:

```
const patientSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  objective: { type: String, required: true }
  notes: [{
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    note: { type: String, required: true }
  }],
});
```

Then when you want to update the objective...

```
const updatePatientObjective = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // check if _id and new objective exist in req.body
    const { _id, objective, date } = req.body;
    if (!_id || !objective) throw "Unable to update patient's objective.";

    // make sure provided _id is valid
    const existingPatient = await Patient.findOne({ _id });
    if (!existingPatient) throw "Unable to locate that patient.";

    // pull out objective as previousObjective 
    const { objective: previousObjective } = existingPatient;

    // update patient's objective while pushing 
    // the previous objective into the notes sub document
    await existingPatient.updateOne({ 
        // update current objective
        $set { objective },
        // push an object with a date and note (previouseObjective) 
        // into a notes array
        $push: { 
          notes: {
            date,
            note: previousObjective              
         },
        },  
      }),
    );

    // send back response
    res
      .status(201)
      .json({ message: "Successfully updated your objective!" });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ err: err.toString() });
  }
};
```

Document will look like:

```
firstName: "John",
lastName: "Smith",
objective: "Lose body fat.",
notes: [
  {
    date: 2019-07-19T17:45:43-07:00,
    note: "Gain muscle".
  },
  { 
    date: 2019-08-09T12:00:38-07:00,
    note: "Work on cardio."
  }
  { 
    date: 2019-08-29T19:00:38-07:00,
    note: "Become a fullstack web developer."
  }
  ...etc
]
```

---

Alternatively, if you're worried about document size, then create a separate schema for patient history and reference the user's id (or just store the patient's _id as a string instead of referencing an ObjectId, whichever you prefer):

```
const patientHistorySchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Patient", required: true },
  objective: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Then create a new patient history document when the objective is updated...

```
PatientHistory.create({ _id, objective: previousObjective });
```

And if you need to access to the patient history documents...

```
PatientHistory.find({ _id });
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! My initial thoughts were to convert the `objective` field into an array (as Liu Wenzhe recommends in a comment below), and make following: `objective: [{ objectiveText: "Gain muscle", timestamp: 2019-08-29T19:00:38-07:00 }]` so every edit would have an objectiveText value and a timestamp, and I could retrieve the last one by sorting those dates. What would you say are the pros and cons of this approach, against your first proposal (the one with the notes array)? Thanks again Matt!

Comment: The only con I can think about my proposal is that I could edit a property 3 times in 1 minute (say the user clicked the button in the UI 3 times), so the objective array would be filled with 2 values that don't actually represent valuable data (probably the user was messing around). To prevent that, I thought about running a daily script that deletes those 2 "extra values" that are not valuable, and keep the last one of that day. This is because of the nature of the property: if you choose to lose fat, that would probably be your objective for the next couple months. What are your thoughts?

Comment: You can do whichever will suit your needs. But if you only want/care about the latest `previousObjective`, then just overwrite the array (using `$set` instead of `$push`) or simply use an object and update its properties. As for preventing duplicates, before updating the document, simply check: `if(objective === previousObjective) throw "Unable to update objective. A new objective must be supplied."`.

Comment: In fact I care about the history and when were those changes produced, in order to perform data analytics on those properties. Right, I think I will stick with the array proposal. Any thoughts on the case that the user hits 3 times a button in a minute? That worries me a bit.

Comment: Yes, see last sentence in my comment above. If the submitted objective is the same, you can throw an error or simply wrap the`existingPatient.updateOne` in a similar condition to ignore it.